# AWS DocumentDB | Regarding read preference options in document db

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I have two instances in my DOCDB cluster, Primary and a read replica. I want to use my Read replica instance for most of the read operations but also want to use Primary instance for few selected queries. I'm planning to create a Documentdb client with below connect URI:

mongodb://staging_docdb:@/?**replicaSet=rs0**&**readPreference=secondaryPreferred**&ssl=true&tlsCAFile=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false

The Above connection string allows me to create a documentdb client in replica set mode and use Read replica for all read operation, as a general rule. Now I see there are few cases where I need to trigger a read operation just after I inserted any resource or updated any resource, In that case because read request goes to immediately read replica instance and there is some lag in Read replica to get the latest updates from primary instance, the read give inconsistent data some times specially for immediately created or updated resources.

I want to configure a readPreference=PrimaryPreferred for few read queries which are getting triggered after immediate create or update of resource.

Can I configure a client with readPreference=secondaryPreferred at the time of client creation and overwrite the readPreference for few specific read queries? I got this idea from the AWS documentation because it says:
*You can set read preference options for a specific query, or as a general option in your MongoDB driver. (Consult your client or driver’s documentation for instructions on how to set a read preference option.)*.

[image]

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/how-it-works.html#durability-consistency-isolation

I went through the AWS documentdb's documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/how-it-works.html#durability-consistency-isolation, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-to-replica-set.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which driver you're using.
For PyMongo, the [documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.read_preference) explains pretty well.

A simple example for Python3 to understand how this works, you need to have the pymongo library installed:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, ReadPreference


##Create a MongoDB client object and specify the read preference as secondary preferred
client = MongoClient('mongodb://docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=global-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false')

##Specify the database to be used
db = client.sample_database

##Specify the collection to be used
col = db.sample_collection

##Insert a single document
col.insert_one({'hello':'Amazon DocumentDB'})

##Create another collection object and specify preference using with_options method
col_primary = col.with_options(read_preference=ReadPreference.PRIMARY)

##Get doc reading from Primary
doc = col_primary.find_one({'hello':'Amazon DocumentDB'})
print("doc: ", doc, "Using preference:", col_primary.read_preference)

##Get doc reading from Secondary
doc = col.find_one({'hello':'Amazon DocumentDB'})
print("doc: ", doc, "Using preference:", col.read_preference)

##Close the connection
client.close()
```